# Small numerical error when calculating Weight Average

Tags: c++, weighted-average, numerical-computing

Here is a part in a Physics engine.
The simplified function `centerOfMass` calculates 1D-center-of-mass of two rigid bodies ([**demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a93968f34657952d)) :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
float centerOfMass(float pos1,float m1, float pos2,float m2){
    return (pos1*m1+pos2*m2)/(m1+m2);
}
int main(){
    float a=5.55709743f;
    float b= centerOfMass(a,50,0,0);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << a << '\n';  //5.55709743
    std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << b << '\n';  //5.55709696
}
```

I need `b` to be precisely = 5.55709743.

The tiny difference can, sometimes (my real case = 5%), introduces a nasty Physics divergence.
There are some ways to solve it e.g. heavily do some conditional checking.
However, it is very error-prone for me.

**Question:** How to solve the calculation error while keep the code clean, fast, and still easily to be maintained?

By the way, if it can't be done elegantly, I would probably need to improve the caller to be more resistant against such numerical error.

### Edit

(clarify duplicate question)

Yes, the cause is the precision error from the storage/computing format (mentioned in [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004)).

However, this question asks about how to ***neutralize*** its symptom in a very specific case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Note that floating point numbers are an inexact approximation to real numbers. Operations with floating point numbers have many well-known limitations.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  Hmm, it is similar.  In my case, I know the cause and I want a workaround, but that question focus on the numerical cause.

Comment: *How to solve the calculation error* what error?

Comment: @CroCo  :  `5.55709743 != 5.55709696` , i.e. a should == b.

Comment: you should not rely on `==` to compare floating-point numbers. In your case, switching from float to double solves your particular case as stated by @Aziz, but you should seriously address the limitations of floating-point representation, otherwise, you will be surprised with the results.

Comment: @CroCo Agree, Aziz's can solve the specific case.  .... In my case, even I never compare it directly, the tiny error can indirectly cause a very small angular velocity on a rigid body that has zero inertia.  It is forbidden in my program. (it is so complex) .... I just dream for a beautiful way that I don't have to check. Now, I come to believe such thing doesn't exist. ... Thank.

Comment: @cppBeginner -- The real issue is that you took a "math book" calculation, and without modification, wrote the computer program equivalent, expecting the same results.   Floating point isn't a math book -- in many cases doing a direct translation will not work for a binary computing machine due to round-off error.  Many formulas had to be rewritten to account for this issue, so in a nutshell, you should do the research so that you can rearrange the calculations in some way to reduce the error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I believe what you meant : there is a solution, and it should not be very hard to find?    As far as I know, there are some techniques e.g. change order of operation, apply distributivity, do some checking if-else.   None of them seems to achieve my objective : beautiful, precise and simple.   I googled "weight average precision/numerical error" , found nothing useful.  May you provide some clues, please?  I probably miss something that is very obvious.

Comment: If you think that you really need accuracy in the seventh digit for your "physics engine", then there's something wrong with that "engine". For example, a bad ODE integration scheme will give wrong results that depend very sensitively on minute variations of the initial conditions. In classical physics such small differences only have a measurable impact in the case of chaotic systems.

Comment: @RHertel  Good to hear.  I fixed other parts instead, and it works now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get 9 decimal digits of precision , but the datatype `float` has a [precision of about 7 decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers).

**Use `double` instead**. ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bdd012741e522b6))

Comment: For `double`, is `a==b` for every `a`?

Comment: This is part of the story but this didn't address the real issue the OP trying to avoid.

Comment: @CroCo  I think so.  I am trying to find such example to show the issue for `double`.

Comment: @cppBeginner - No, assuming a is "near" 1.0, a and b will sometimes differ by an amount on the order of 1e-15. Taking an example off the top of my head, a=6.7820743978696196 will yield b=6.7820743978696187

Answer (score 1):

Use double, not float.  IEEE 754 double has about 16 decimal places of precision.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
double centerOfMass(double pos1, double m1, double pos2, double m2) {
    return (pos1*m1 + pos2 * m2) / (m1 + m2);
}
int main() {
    double a = 5.55709743;
    double b = centerOfMass(a, 50, 0, 0);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << a << '\n';  //5.55709743
    std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << b << '\n';  //5.55709743
    std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << (b - a) << '\n';  // 0
}
```

For the example given, centerOfMass(a, 50, 0, 0), the following will give exact results for all values of a, but of course the example does not look realistic.

```
double centerOfMass(double pos1, double m1, double pos2, double m2) {
    double divisor = m1 + m2;
    return pos1*(m1/divisor) + pos2*(m2/ divisor);
}
```

Comment: Will it still have the same issue - but in a different numerical degree?

Comment: @cppBeginner - Yes, always. If your a's are "close" to 1.0, the difference between a and b will be of the order 1e-15 (assuming IEEE 754 double). Taking an example off the top of my head, a=6.7820743978696196 will yield b=6.7820743978696187

Comment: Thank for the number! Can I get rid ALL of the issue?  I mean - not just alleviate it.   PaulMcKenzie (comment near OP's) somehow mentioned that it is possible to re-arrange the formula, but I don't know how.

Comment: @cppBeginner Can't be done without an infinite amount of memory, and who can afford that?

Comment: @cppBeginner - Rearranging the formula is not likely to help much if any.